# Ошибка синтаксиса

Tags: javascript

Как правильно написать ?

```
gradient.style.background-image = "-webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(70,70,70,0.8) 0%, transparent 100%)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gradient.style.backgroundImage`: в джаваскрипте свойства style пишутся camelcase'ом.

Comment: Не пашит gradient.style.backgroundImage = "-webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(70,70,70,0.8) 0%, transparent 100%)"

Comment: Значит, проблема где-то в другом месте, например, в определении элемента gradient. Попробуйте на Хэшкоде выполнить в консоли:  

    document.getElementById('room').style.backgroundImage = '-webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(70,70,70,0.8) 0%, transparent 100%)';